# Comparing table data to a string

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm trying to find out if data from my DB matches user input. I have tried this code, but its not doing what I need it to do. I would like it to display a message saying whether or not they match.

```
 try {
        String find = BC.getText(); //Get text from Textfield
        String sql = "select * from Inventory where Barcode=?";
        st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = st.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            if("Barcode".equals(find))
            {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Matching");  

            }   
            else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"not matching");   
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {


    }
```

Comment: How you use **executeQuery()** before set the value of **?**

Comment: In addition to not setting your query's parameter, you are not actually using the results of the `ResultSet` from the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the parameter that you want to search.See this;

```
 String find = BC.getText(); //Get text from Textfield
 String sql = "select * from Inventory where Barcode=?";
 st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
 st.setString(1, "12345678");//Set Barcode value.
 rs = st.executeQuery();
```